# Where do different icons appear on Android?

Tags: android, icons

I’m trying to figure out where different icon files appear on a device.

– For example, if the notification icon in the status bar is the same one that appears in the notification drawer. See attached image for more a better explaination.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notification icons are set in the `Notification.Builder`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)

The difference in the picture on the right is because one shows a locked phone and the other shows unlocked.

Comment: Thanks, but is it the same icon source? I mean, if I make one notification status icon, will it appear in the status bar and in the drawer? In the screenshots they have different backgrounds and colors - Can this be controlled?

Comment: By drawer you mean the app drawer? No, Icons in the app drawer are defined in the manifest of your app. Notifications use whatever you set them to be in the `setSmallIcon` and `setLargeIcon` methods

Comment: By drawer I think I mean the "notification drawer" (I'm a designer and iOs user...) In the example above one can see a notification icon for the calendar in the status bar - but there is also one calendar icon on a blue circle in the notification drawer. Is it the same icon that the system is using or is it two different icons?

Comment: The youtube and music icons are not system icons. They are icons that the app is specifying. Notifications use whatever you set them to be in the `setSmallIcon` and `setLargeIcon` methods. Why don't you just create a notification in a demo app and you will see exactly what is used and where. Icons in the notification bar are always white in Lollipop and above but  will show in their full colour when seen on the lock screen or notification shade.

Comment: Hmhm, I understand that they are not system icons and that I can design them. I just wonder if they are the same. 

–And to answer your question about why I not just create a demo app – I'm a designer and and iOs user :D

Comment: iOs users are allowed to make Android apps too.